Gradle project sync failed basic functionality


Что делал:

Удалял кэш
а) Директории
%userprofile%\.gradle\caches
[путь к проекту]\.gradle
[путь к проекту]\.idea
б) В Android Studio -> Menu -> Invalidate cache

Сопоставлял версии скаченного SDK, c теми что указаны в конфигурационных секциях build.gradle
compileSdk и targetSdk





Версия SDK в проекте
Скаченная версия SDK
Virtual Device API











Сопоставлял совместимость версии gradle c плагином com.android.application
Судя по данным из ссылка: версия плагина = 8.5.1 совместима с grafle 8.7 и выше
(пробовал переключаться между 8.9 и 8.7 версией)

Результат выполнения команды  gradle installDebug - УСПЕШНЫЙ


Много гуглил и видел много подобных вопросов, но рекомендации из них мне не помогли. (или я что то упустил)
что можно ещё посмотреть?


Что есть в логе %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2024.1\log*idea.log*
INFO - #com.android.studio.ml.aida.AidaModelProvider - No geo-lock detected for Studio Bot, but check failed
aida.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED
    at aida.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:275)
....
WARN - #o.j.p.g.s.e.GradleExecutionHelper - Gradle execution error
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:87)

2024-08-07 15:27:16,293 [1172553]   INFO - #c.i.o.e.u.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [E:/*****/MyApplication] resolution task started
2024-08-07 15:27:16,295 [1172555]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncStateHolder$SyncStateUpdater - onStart(RESOLVE_PROJECT:3, E:/*****/MyApplication)
2024-08-07 15:27:16,295 [1172555]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncStateHolder$SyncStateUpdaterService - trackTask(RESOLVE_PROJECT:3, E:/*****/MyApplication)
2024-08-07 15:27:16,295 [1172555]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncStateHolder - Started (TRIGGER_PROJECT_REOPEN) sync with Gradle for project 'MyApplication'.
2024-08-07 15:27:16,379 [1172639]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:27:16,380 [1172640]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:27:16,390 [1172650]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.studio.tooling contents "initscript {\n    dependencies {\n        classpath files([mapPath('F:/*****/Android Studio/plugins/android/lib/android-gradle.jar'), mapPath('F:/*****/Android Studio/plugins/android/lib/android-gradle.jar'), mapPath('F:/*****/Android Studio/lib/util-8.jar')])\n    }\n}\nallprojects {\n    apply plugin: com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin\n}\n"
2024-08-07 15:27:16,397 [1172657]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:27:16,402 [1172662]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncStateHolder$SyncStateUpdater - onFailure(RESOLVE_PROJECT:3, com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp)
2024-08-07 15:27:16,402 [1172662]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncStateHolder$SyncStateUpdaterService - stopTrackingTask(RESOLVE_PROJECT:3)
2024-08-07 15:27:16,402 [1172662]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncStateHolder - Gradle sync failed in 107 ms. C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp
2024-08-07 15:27:16,404 [1172664]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:27:16,406 [1172666]   INFO - #c.i.o.e.u.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [E:/*****/MyApplication] resolution task executed in 112 ms.
2024-08-07 15:27:16,407 [1172667]   INFO - #com.google.services.firebase.insights.config.FirebaseAppManager - New app states: {}.
2024-08-07 15:27:16,713 [1172973]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:27:16,714 [1172974]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:27:16,733 [1172993]   INFO - #c.i.a.o.PathMacrosImpl - Saved path macros: {}
2024-08-07 15:27:16,736 [1172996]   INFO - #c.i.o.e.s.p.m.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 19 ms
2024-08-07 15:27:18,100 [1174360]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:27:18,101 [1174361]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:27:39,737 [1195997]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:27:39,738 [1195998]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:28:08,495 [1224755]   WARN - #c.i.i.a.CopyTBXReferenceAction - Cannot find TBX tool for IDE: AndroidStudio
2024-08-07 15:28:54,891 [1271151]   INFO - #c.i.e.w.WslDistributionManager - Fetched WSL distributions: [] ("C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --list --verbose" done in 73 ms)
2024-08-07 15:29:13,115 [1289375]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:29:13,116 [1289376]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:29:13,129 [1289389]   INFO - #c.i.a.o.PathMacrosImpl - Saved path macros: {}
2024-08-07 15:29:13,310 [1289570]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:29:13,311 [1289571]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:29:13,499 [1289759]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=MyApplication, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=E:\*****\MyApplication)RunManager took 72 ms, ServiceViewManager took 14 ms, deploymentTargetSelector took 22 ms, editorHistoryManager took 26 ms
2024-08-07 15:29:36,970 [1313230]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:29:36,970 [1313230]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:29:37,112 [1313372]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:29:37,113 [1313373]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:29:37,129 [1313389]   INFO - #c.i.a.o.PathMacrosImpl - Saved path macros: {}
2024-08-07 15:29:42,225 [1318485]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:29:42,226 [1318486]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:29:43,365 [1319625]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:29:43,366 [1319626]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:31:22,375 [1418635]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:31:22,375 [1418635]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from F:*****\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-07 15:31:23,384 [1419644]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-07 15:31:23,385 [1419645]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files


